# makefile: cannot build project

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC = /usr/bin

CPPFLAGS = -x c++
...
```

When I build my project with this makefile I get:

```
make: execvp: /usr/bin/: Permission denied
```

There is a way to specify root permission in the makefile ? Or other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to run `/usr/bin`? `CC` is usually set to a C compiler, not a directory.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I changed to: CC = /usr/bin/g++-4.4 and I could build.

Answer (score 1):

Either comment out the CC line or set it to be the full path to the C compiler.

The shell command `which cc` will give you a path to the C compiler